# Facebook application, check users likes and display message

Tags: php, facebook, web-applications, facebook-fbml

Hey i want to check a whether a user likes a certain page and if they do i want to display a message or div? I have searched through the facebook forums for possible solutions but i never came upon anything concrete so i would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't understand your Question, maybe you could explain your situation and re-type your questions with paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this through FQL. To check if a user likes some URL:

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id in (SELECT id from object_url WHERE url="<PAGE_URL>") and user_id=<USER_ID>;
```

If query is empty then a user doesn't like this url. Otherwise 1 record is returned.

See [`like`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like), [`object_url`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/object_url).

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Ok basically what i am looking to do.

 1. Check whether a user is a fan of a certain url or page
 2. If yes, display message